# React - prop function within prop function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to execute a prop within another prop for one of my components. Basically I have to wait for some data to come back from an API then i'd like to execute the next prop. Here is my components 2 props code:

```
getReportId = () => {

// here I make a call to the API to get a unique report ID
// then I set the state of my component to the ID's value and try call the next function

this.setState({
    reportID: reportID
});

//here is where im trying to move onto the next part  but its not firing
this.getReportData;

}

getReportData = () => {
// here would be part 2 where I would get the data based off the report ID but its not firing..
}
```

Not sure if this is the correct approach in React to begin with? If so then not sure why the prop is not firing...

Comment: Did you miss method getReportData call `this.getReportData();` ?

Comment: Could you please write a whole component so that i could give the answer

Comment: Also, a reminder that state changes occur after the completion of the currently executing block. You would not have access to the new `this.state.reportId` in `getReportData`. Instead probably pass it through as an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Sven ten Haaf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4691187/sven-ten-haaf) pointed out, you are not actually calling the function. But it looks like you're not taking into account the asynchronous nature of your code either, which would also be a problem.

Calling an API means that the rest of your logic needs to wait until that API has responded with the data you need for the remaining steps.

You don't say how you are calling this API, but here's how I would do it if I was doing an AJAX call with jQuery:

```
getReportId = () => {
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/myApi/someFunction",
    data : inputData,
    success: (data) => {
      this.setState({
        reportID: data.reportID
      }, () => {
        this.getReportData();  //this is the setState callback
      });
    }
  });   
}

getReportData = () => {
  ...
}
```

---

If you are unfamiliar with the `setState()` callback, have a look at the official docs [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

> The second parameter is an optional callback function that will be executed once `setState` is completed and the component is re-rendered.
>
> ```
> setState(nextState, callback);
> ```

Comment: Yes I had the call back in the success part of the function but I didn't know about the second optional callback in setState so will use that! The original problem was the missing ()

Comment: Excellent! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

The reason your function is not firing is because you didn't invoke it.

Use `this.getReportData();`

I'm not sure you're on the right track though, I'd have to see the whole component for that.